# How to show multiple location markers using Google Map API?

Tags: java, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Problem description:**

I have to develop an application using Dynamic Google Map in Spring MVC to show multiple 'Bubble Markers' using address/postal code
and I have to show zooming facility for this map, when I click on that Bubble it have to show the corresponding address or postal code.

**What I did yet :**

I have implemented static Google map to show multiple 'Bubble markers' using postal code. 
As following code

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=099419&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&markers=color:blue|label:S|416416|238843
```

*One more problem with this static way, I can not put many postal code because of fixed length of URL.*

so how can I implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow this sample of goolge maps and make an array of marker.
[Link](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)

Or this:
[Link2](http://www.blesciasw.it/?p=39)

Comment: I tried to show graph according to first link,and I am able to show graph but it is showing me an 'OVER_QUERY_LIMIT' error.

Comment: how much marker do you add on maps? see this link if you are in the range of free google map's api. https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

Comment: If you see corresponding cell with name "Geocoding Web Service" you have 2500 queries. If you want to locate 1000 marker you can refresh the page only 2,5 times.(1000+1000+500)

Comment: can I place 300 to 400 address on map ? and what I have to do to place that address on map ? is there is any solution to place that address same time on map ?

Comment: remember you can execute only 2500 queries per days and i don't know if are present an another way to solve this problem. sorry